# Node Js prints [object Object] does not print session information

Tags: node.js, soap, soapui

I am using the following Node Js code to use the Web service. But when I run this on Postman, I got `[object Object]` in console. But when I run on SoapUI, it will print the Session details

**my code**

```
router.post("/register", upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next)
{
  var url = 'http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV2/EnterpriseSMSWS?wsdl';

  var session = {username: 'username', password: 'password'} 

  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client)
  {
    if(err)
    console.log(err)
    client.createSession(session, function(err, result)
    {
      console.log(result);
    });

  })
})
```

**SoapUI session request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.esms.mobitel.lk/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:createSession>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <customer>12</customer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <id>12</id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <password>password</password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <username>username</username>
         </arg0>
      </ws:createSession>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**SoapUI response**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.esms.mobitel.lk/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:createSessionResponse>
         <return>
            <expiryDate>2018-10-04T06:24:25+05:30</expiryDate>
            <isActive>true</isActive>
            <sessionId>761033662786</sessionId>
            <user>0</user>
         </return>
      </ns1:createSessionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**wrap the code into try catch**

```
Error: SOAP-ENV:Server: Procedure 'createSession' not present
{"statusCode":500,"body":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Procedure 'createSession' not present</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n","headers":{"date":"Thu, 04 Oct 2018 08:51:04 GMT","server":"Apache/2.2.15
(CentOS)","x-powered-by":"PHP/5.3.3","content-length":"304","connection":"close","content-type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"202.129.232.190:8585","port":"8585","hostname":"202.129.232.190","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/EnterpriseSMSV2/EnterpriseSMSWS.php","path":"/EnterpriseSMSV2/EnterpriseSMSWS.php","href":"http://202.129.232.190:8585/EnterpriseSMSV2/EnterpriseSMSWS.php"},"method":"POST","headers":{"User-Agent":"node-soap/0.8.0","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"none","Accept-Charset":"utf-8","Connection":"close","Host":"202.129.232.190:8585","Content-Length":0,"Content-Type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8","SOAPAction":"\"\""}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are requesting REST API.

`Response format for SOAP UI is XML.` But for `REST API is JSON`. Then your are getting JSON format response. Thats why you are getting `[object object]` when you try to print that. So check out how to handle JSON.

Comment: Yeah I used `JSON.stringify` but I got Response 500

Comment: put all this code inside `try{  // your current code } catch(err){ console.log(err) }`. Find what is the exact internal server issue. Just post the consoled log data

Comment: It says `'createSession' not present`. Please see the updated post.

Comment: yep..SoapUI response has `createSessionResponse` Block. But SoapUI session request has `createSession`. Check with backend. This is not on your side.